# Ambiguous reference to member 'print' - (scope within Swift closure?)

Tags: swift, closures

This compiles:

```
let s = SignalsService()
s.addListener( "key", callback: { a, b in print( "success" ) } )
```

This does not:

```
let s = SignalsService()
let cb = { a, b in print( "success" ) }
s.addListener( "key", callback: cb )
```

Throwing the error `Ambiguous reference to member 'print'` at the `let cb = ...` line.

Why is that then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In

```
s.addListener( "key", callback: { a, b in print( "success" ) } )
```

the compiler can infer the type of the closure from the context,
i.e. from the type of the `addListener()` method. If that method is
for example declared as

```
func addListener(key : String, callback: (Int, Int) -> Void)
```

then the compiler can infer that the argument

```
{ a, b in print( "success" )
```

is a closure taking two `Int` parameters and returning `Void`.

In

```
let cb = { a, b in print( "success" ) }
```

there is no such context, therefore the compiler cannot know
the type of the closure. The return type can be inferred as
`Void` because the closure consists of a single expression,
but you have to specify the types of the parameters, e.g.

```
let cb = { (a : Int, b : Int) in print( "success" ) }
```

Comment: Also, you get this error when the callback function should return a value, but you have not typed `return value` into the closure yet...

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @MartinR's excellent answer.

Swift needs to be able to infer that `cb` is of type `(Int, Int)->()`, or you could explicitly set the type:

```
let cb: (Int, Int)->() = { a, b in print( "success" ) }
```

Then you could notice that `a` and `b` are unused and replace them with `_`:

```
let cb: (Int, Int)->() = { _ in print( "success" ) }
```

*Why can we get away with a single `_` when the function takes 2 parameters?*  In this case, Swift knows there are 2 parameters, so the `_` takes the place of the tuple containing all of the parameters.  It replaces `(_, _)`.

---

You can use `_` with @MartinR's answer:

```
let cb = { (_:Int, _:Int) in print( "success" ) }
```

or you can write it like:

```
let cb = { (_:(Int, Int)) in print( "success" ) }
```

which can be read as:

> `cb` takes two parameters of type `Int` which it ignores and prints
>   "success"